# Redirecting on inside of Facebook Canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, redirect, facebook-canvas

I'm developing a Facebook application. It's on www.domain.com . **App on Facebook** option selected on **Select how your app integrates with Facebook** section of settings page of  app.
And www.domain.com is setted as *canvas url* .

In shortly, my apps url : http://apps.facebook.com/name and apps' canvas url is : http://domain.com .

It's working perfectly but on registration process of my app, i need to redirect to **http://domain.com/addnew** . When i use JS redirection , it's exiting from Facebook and visiting http://domain.com/addnew . But i want to redirect on inside of Facebook (on canvas frame).

I hope you will understood me.

Answer (score 2):

You must do it through Javasript, like so:

```
<script>
top.location="http://someurl.com";
</script>
```